# Why did Boost's `bcp smart_ptr dir/` copy 6MB of source code?

Tags: boost, bcp

So I wanted to separate out just the smart pointers from boost to use in my project and I was guided to use `bcp` utility.

Today I got it compiled and did `bcp smart_ptr to_copy_to_my_project/`.

The result: 6MB of code in `to_copy_to_my_project/` directory.

Are you kidding me? I don't want to add 6MB of header files to my 100KB project just to use smart pointers.

For example, it copies the following win32 stuff (I am on Linux):

```
Copying file: boost/thread/win32/basic_timed_mutex.hpp
Copying file: boost/thread/win32/condition_variable.hpp
Copying file: boost/thread/win32/interlocked_read.hpp
```

Why would it copy win32 stuff with smart_ptr when I am on Linux?

Also:

```
Copying file: boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/msvc60/advance_backward.hpp
...
Copying file: boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/msvc70/advance_backward.hpp
...
Copying file: boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/mwcw/advance_backward.hpp
```

And:

```
Copying file: boost/date_time/adjust_functors.hpp
```

Why does smart_ptr depend on date_time?

Also what about all these tests that it copied over:

```
Copying file: libs/smart_ptr/test/allocate_shared_esft_test.cpp
...
```

I don't need any of it! I just need smart_ptr!

Did I do something wrong? Why did it copy 6MB of code just for the smart pointers, which I would expect to be 10KB or 20KB...

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Comment: For those who don't know what bcp is: http://www.digipedia.pl/man/doc/view/bcp.1/

Comment: I am using gcc. Do you have any tips to get it smaller? I now have it down to 3mb after deleting many compiler related stuff and tests.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is `smart_ptr` and you're not interested in `#define`'ing `BOOST_SP_USE_QUICK_ALLOCATOR` (which is not defined by default), you only need:

```
boost/assert.hpp
boost/checked_delete.hpp
boost/config.hpp
boost/config/compiler/*
boost/config/no_tr1/functional.hpp
boost/config/no_tr1/memory.hpp
boost/config/no_tr1/utility.hpp
boost/config/platform/*
boost/config/posix_features.hpp
boost/config/select_compiler_config.hpp
boost/config/select_platform_config.hpp
boost/config/select_stdlib_config.hpp
boost/config/stdlib/*
boost/config/suffix.hpp
boost/config/user.hpp
boost/current_function.hpp
boost/detail/interlocked.hpp
boost/detail/sp_typeinfo.hpp
boost/detail/workaround.hpp
boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp
boost/exception/detail/attribute_noreturn.hpp
boost/exception/exception.hpp
boost/memory_order.hpp
boost/non_type.hpp
boost/shared_ptr.hpp
boost/smart_ptr/*
boost/throw_exception.hpp
boost/type.hpp
```

This comes to 365k, with the bulk of the code actually in `boost/smart_ptr`.  There is still a lot of code in `boost/config`.  If you know what platforms you're targeting, you could pare down `boost/config/compiler`, `boost/config/platform`, and `boost/config/stdlib`.  Then the vast majority of the code would be in `boost/smart_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the stl's shared pointer: `std::tr1::shared_ptr`, which for all intents and purposes "is" `boost::shared_ptr`.

Comment: But then it requires I compile my code with -std=c++0x, right?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you could delete the test and win32 folders--they are probably only included when testing or on that platform.  I can't speak to most of the header files, but I know smart_ptr does lots of crazy stuff so that you can convert boost::shared_ptr<Foo> into boost::shared_ptr<const Foo>, which most templates can't do.  If you'd like a counting pointer that fits in only a few files, it's not hard to write one, but it won't be as nice as boost.

Since you say you're on Linux, why not just list boost as a dependency?

Comment: Listing boost as a dependency is pretty scary - it's 37MB compressed and over 100MB decompressed. For my 100KB application, that's 1000 fold overhead...

Comment: Most Linux systems already have boost.  Your small application won't be the only thing using it.  Redistributing boost inside your application is wasteful.

Comment: behavior and facilities varies with versions. It is not as simple as "list boost as a dependency"

Comment: The Smart Pointer portion of boost (which the question is referring to) is unchanged since 1.34.0 in 2007.

Comment: If you are just using the shared pointer then that's a header-only library so you won't need to redistribute anything with your app.

Answer (score 0):

The reason being that boost supports a myriad platforms and compilers and boost modules uses other boost modules liberally. Even though most of it will be #ifdef:ed away bcp isn't smart enough to do that.

I had a similar issue so  I understand your concern. I tried running the preprocessor with out platform settings then the code became significantly smaller.

In the end though we upgraded the compiler to the version that supports C++ tr1 and use std::tr1::shared_ptr.

One might argue that 6Megs are a small price to pay for industry standard smart pointers however not all developers/architects feel the same way and since I'm no despot yet I had to go with what the team decides.

Answer (score 0):

`bcp` will copy a lot less if you do

```
bcp shared_ptr.hpp to_copy_to_my_project/.
```

It still seems like way too much, I agree.