# Does boost graph really need 40 MB of files?

Tags: boost, boost-graph

I want to use boost graph and so I've extracted it with bcp. The thing is it's copied almost 40 MB of files. It seems like a lot to me, but I really don't know. I guess there are lots of things for different platforms and many things I probably won't use.

So, is there any way of extracting just what I need, for my platform and all, apart from doing it by hand, or I better stick with the whole graph library?

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve ? Are you short of disk space or something like that ?

Comment: No, not really. Actually, a bigger, faster HDD would come handy, but it's not that. It just seemed like a lot. In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3484585/385646) someone had a similar problem with smart_ptr and one of the solutions reduced the size from 6 MB to less than 400 KB, by picking just the files needed.

Comment: Unless you have storage issues it doesn't seem worth the time and effort required to prune the files, especially given that (a) you'll need to repeat the exercise whenever you upgrade to a newer version and (b) you may find later that you need some functionality which you have removed and will then have to start adding files back in again.

Comment: Ok, so there's no magic switch to tell bcp "just take what I need for my platform"... Thanks, then, I'll leave it as is.